# AnyLogic : All the delays are full So new agent is not suppose to enter according to condition

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

Of the conditions I listed in `SelectOutput8`, one of them must be true every time.

But that is not the case, and it seems like there is no reason for that.
Details are shown in the image below.

[image]

The problem is the delay2, delay4, delay7 is full So no new agent needs to enter according to the condition but that is not the case.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First i have to say that those seize/release blocks are completely useless and probably are just a desperate way you are using to solve the problem

Now, according to your model, there is absolutely nothing blocking your model to move an agent to your seize block because the condition clearly states that if delay1 is free, the agent can exit delay (and in your picture, delay1.size IS equal to zero)

I don't know what you have in selectOutput7 though

Comment: In my SelectOutput7 i have these conditions, condition one  `agent.paint;` condition2 `agent.repair;` condition 3 `agent.bwork`; condition4 `false`.

Kindly let me know how can I avoid extra agents moving forward and use one seize to transfer these sources to their destination.

Comment: your selectOutput conditions are not aligned with your delay conditions.. you need to rebuild your model from scratch thinking more closely on what you are doing... this model you have here is extremely bad so i can't advise on how to fix it, i can only tell you start again

Comment: I think the main problem is when an agent gets free. it doesn't know where exactly needs to go.  I did make it from scratch again, in a new way, but still getting the problem I will share it in a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking select block, you can try with multiple split block. Split blocks allow you to change or create new agent.